# Finding out what type a certain interface is

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, types

I am creating a method that accepts a IOBJECT parameter. there is multiple class that implement this interface. I need to figure out which type IOBJECT is. how would i go about doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you can use the "is" operator. Throw it into a switch of if else statment to figure things out.

```
if(obj is ClassA) {
    //sweetness
} else if (obj is ClassB) {
    //awesomeness
}
```

typeof will not work, as suggested in the other reply. It will likely return "object" in all cases. instanceof will work though.

Comment: So, how would i implement the"is" or the instanceof in a Case Statement ?

Comment: Ya don't use a case, use if else's. You could use switch if you were working with getQualifiedClassName(), but just use if else, its simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [typeof](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary810.html), [instanceof](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary389.html), or [the 'is' operator](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#is)

Answer (score 0):

You can do getQualifiedClassName() to get the class name of the object. You can also use describeType() which gives you a more complete description of all the methods and properties of the object.

There is information about both here: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html

It doesn't sound like an ideal situation though. You may want to do something where you can standardize the way you handle all items. For example:

```
public interface IObject { 
    function doSomething():void;
}
```

Then...

```
function myMethod(obj:IObject):void {
    obj.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. BUt I want to do something with obj, store it in particular varibles depending on the type. So I need to use the case statement to find out what type it is. just trying to figure out how to apply the is or instanceof with the case statement.

Comment: it appears that I cant call a method from within the Interface data type, I have to cast it back to its orginal type in order for it to work. in order words. iobj.doSomething();
 doesnt work. but Object(iobj).doSomething(); does. am i missing something ?